# azure ad scope in on behalf of flow always retusns all the consented scopes

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to build an application that runs as a nodejs/react application. it calls an external api that is also registered in azure ad using the onbehalf of flow.

based on the user logged in, i want to request certain scopes to be passed to the service on behalf of the logged in user. my code looks like this:

```
const request = require('request');

function getApiTokenOnBehalfOf(req, callback) {

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form:
        {
            assertion: req.user.accessToken,
            grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            client_id: process.env.PASSPORT_AZUREAD_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.PASSPORT_AZUREAD_SECRET,
            scope: 'https://`myorg.com/api/Users.Read.All',
            requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of'
        }
    };

    request(options, callback);

}
```

for some reason the scopes returned in the token always include *all* the scopes the user has ever consented to for this application. how do i restrict the tokens returned to the user to just the ones i ask for in the call?

Comment: Can you clarify what the requests are from the original auth and then the 2nd auth request? If you're trying to get an access token to access a different resource it shouldn't matter, because the Audience will be different. However, if you use the default scope it should only return static permissions. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get an access token to access a different resource, the scps and permissions shouldn't matter, because the Audiences will be different.

However, if you are really trying to control the permissions with a fine tooth comb, the default scope will only return static permissions so that only the permissions you are expecting should be returned via the access token. Please see the docs here for more information in regards to this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope

Comment: I am trying to keep the scopes to a minimum but my key problem here is that when I use the code above. It isn't just returning that one scope but all scopes the user ever consented to. The only way go get it out is by removing the consent from azure ad.  Maybe I don't understand the dynamic consent stuff but it is weird to get more scopes than I request for.

Comment: Even the refresh token flow has the same behavior.